# Get total number from multiple post object fields

Tags: php, object, post, advanced-custom-fields

I'm pretty new to PHP so my question might have a very simple answer, but I've searched the ACF forum and Google with no luck. Hopefully someone here can help.

I have four multi-select post object fields on my page and I'm attempting to get the total number of posts (or in my case staff) in those post objects. I'd like to combine them somehow so I can use the total with a conditional.

I'm able to get the amount for a single post object using `count()`.

```
$instructor = get_field('course_instructors');

if (count($instructors) > 1) {
  // dosomething...
}
```

but trying to add them together within `count()` doesn't work.

```
$instructor = get_field('course_instructors');
$leaders = get_field('course_leaders');
$designers = get_field('course_designers');
$speakers = get_field('course_speakers');

if (count($instructors + $leaders + $designers + $speakers) > 1) {
  // dosomething...
}
```

I've also tried `array_merge()` and other array functions with no luck, but I'm not 100% sure that the output of a post object is an array...although it looks like it when I use `print_r()`.

Ideally my code would work something like this:

```
$instructor = get_field('course_instructors');
$leaders = get_field('course_leaders');
$designers = get_field('course_designers');
$speakers = get_field('course_speakers');
$all_staff = $instructors + $leaders + $designers + $speakers;

if (count($all_staff) > 1) {
  // dosomething...
}
```

When I do that I get an error: "Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in...".

Hopefully someone can answer this for me or at least point in the right direction.
Thanks in advance. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that ended up working for me:
(based on suggestions provided by John Huebner on [my post on the ACF support forum](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-total-count-from-multiple-post-object-fields/).)

```
$instructors_total = 0;
$instructors = get_field('instructors');
if (is_array($instructors)) {
  $instructors_total = count($instructors);
}

$leaders_total = 0;
$leaders = get_field('leaders');
if (is_array($leaders)) {
  $leaders_total = count($leaders);
}

$designers_total = 0;
$designers = get_field('designers');
if (is_array($designers)) {
  $designers_total = count($designers);
}

$speakers_total = 0;
$speakers = get_field('speakers');
if (is_array($speakers)) {
  $speakers_total = count($speakers);
}

$staff_total = $instructors_total + $leaders_total + $designers_total + $speakers_total;
```

As mentioned above, this is based on both of @hube2's recommendations except that I'm using `count()` inside my `is_array()` validations rather than outside of them. Using `count()` to add the totals together outside the validation was returning a '1' even if the array was empty. So if all of my arrays were empty, I was still getting '4'. The [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php/#refsect1-function.count-returnvalues) doc states: "If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned."

There might be a better way to do this, but this is working well for me.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the good track, but PHP's [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) only accepts one mixed object/array at once, so you should go with:

```
if ( count($instructors) + count($leaders) + count($designers) + count($speakers) > 1) {
    // dosomething...
}
```

Or you could keep the result in a variable in case you need to reuse it later in your code:

```
$count = count($instructors) + count($leaders) + count($designers) + count($speakers);

if ( $count > 1 ) {
     // dosomething...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to be working. I used print_r() to see what value I was getting and it's giving me the number of arrays (4) rather than the total number of objects in the 4 arrays. It's very strange since I'm able to get the correct number if I use count() on an individual post object.

Comment: Can you post `print_r`'s output for at least one of your variables?

Comment: Thank you again for responding! I was able to find a solution for my issue on the ACF forum...where I also [posted this question](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-total-count-from-mult‌​iple-post-object-fields/#post-37252). I have added my solution as an answer on this page.

Comment: You're welcome @SeanVinci :) Good point by hube2 noticing what `count` docs say: _If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned._